# How to make both widgets in the same height?

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, styles

I have issue with one of my footer widget in Wordpress [site](http://raion.asia/). When add more then 2 lines in adress widget, automatically, second contact widget goes down, and its not alligned in height. How to make both widgets to show in same position?

Image from issue:

[image: issue]

Both widgets have the same CSS class:

```css
.footer-contact-block
```

Comment: Dora, please include the code necessary to reproduce your issue http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. With just a screenshot, all we can do is take guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use :

```
.footer-contact { display: table; } 
.footer-contact-block { display: table-cell; }
```

You'll get both widgets at the same height.

That's what you want?

Comment: Thanks ! That fixed my issue.